# Question on proof of linearity of expectation involving discrete random variables

Tags: probability, proof-verification

Please see the proof below regarding the linearity of expectation given two discrete random variables $X$ and $Y$. I'm not understanding how the first highlighted step moves to the next highlighted step. I've looked online and seen mention that this relates to the law of total probability... but after looking up some more information on the law of total probability I can't see how this law is applied here.

$$\begin{align*}E[X+Y]&=\sum_x\sum_y [(x+y)\cdot P(X=x, Y=y)]\\
&=\sum_x\sum_y [x\cdot P(X=x, Y=y)]+\sum_x\sum_y [y\cdot P(X=x, Y=y)]\\&=\bbox[yellow]{\sum_xx\sum_y P(X=x, Y=y)+\sum_xy\sum_y [P(X=x, Y=y)]}\\
&=\bbox[yellow]{\sum_x x \cdot P(X=x)+\sum_y y\cdot P(Y=y)}\\
&=E[X]+E[Y]\end{align*}$$

Comment: If you just think about it, the probability that $X$ takes the value $x$, written as $P(X = x)$, is equal to the sum of the probabilities of $X$ equaling $x$ and $Y$ equaling $y$ for all possible $y$.  In other words, when $X = x$, each $y$ is a "case", i.e., a possible value that $Y$ can take.  So to just get $P(X = x)$ you can sum up the probabilities of all the "cases" $\sum \limits_{y} P(X = x \text{ and } Y = y)$.

Comment: @user46944 But how do you guarantee the discrete random variable $Y$ has the same number of cases as $X$? For instance, if $X=\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ and $Y=\{3,4,5\}$?

Comment: You don't need any such guarantee. You just sum the value of X times the probability of the outcome for all possible outcomes. $$\sum\limits_{\omega\in\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}{\times}\{3,4,5\}} X(\omega)\,\Bbb P\{\omega\}$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The missing step is just that probability is additive for disjoint unions, and the support of a random variable partitions the sample space.   Also known as the *Law of Total Probability*.

$$\begin{align}\mathsf E(X+Y) &=\sum_x\sum_y (x+y)~\mathsf P(X=x\cap Y=y) \\[1ex] &= \sum_x\sum_y x~\mathsf P(X=x\cap Y=y)+\sum_x\sum_y y~\mathsf P(X=x\cap Y=y)\\[1ex]&=\sum_x x \sum_y\mathsf P(X=x\cap Y=y)+\sum_y y\sum_x\mathsf P(X=x\cap Y=y) \\[1ex] &= \sum_x x~\mathsf P\Bigl((X=x)\cap \bigcup_y (Y=y)\Bigr)+\sum_y y~\mathsf P\Bigl((Y=y)\cap\bigcup_x(X=x)\Bigr)\tag{$\bigstar$}\\[1ex] &= \sum_{x}x~\mathsf P(X=x)+\sum_{y}y~\mathsf P(Y=y)\\[1ex] &= \mathsf E(X)+\mathsf E(Y)\end{align}$$

PS: If you could write all probabilities of pairs of $(X,Y)$ values in a tabular grid and sum the values in the rows and columns into the margins, those values are the *marginal probability masses*.   This is where the name comes from.$$\mathsf P(X=x)=\sum_y \mathsf P(X=x, Y=y)$$

Comment: I'm still struggling just a bit with this... so just to be clear then $P(X=x)$ is the probability density function... so when I'm looking at this notation $\sum_y P(X=x, Y=y)$ when am I going through the entire range of all $x\in X$? For instance, considering $X=\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ and $Y=\{3,4,5\}$ would it work as follows: $P(X=1\vert Y=3)\cdot P(Y=3) + P(X=2\vert Y=3)\cdot P(Y=3) + P(X=3\vert Y=3)\cdot P(Y=3) + \cdots + P(X=6\vert Y=3)\cdot P(Y=3)$ and then starting the sum again at $P(X=1\vert Y=4)\cdot P(Y=4)$?

Comment: @ClownInTheMoon No; it is for any particular value of $x$, not all of them. The $y$ subscript of the sigma-operator indicates *that* is summing over all possible $y$ values (that lead to non-zero terms); in this case, the support of $Y$.  $$\begin{align}\mathsf P(X{=}x)~&=~\sum_y \mathsf P(X{=}x, Y{=}y) \\[1ex]& =~\mathsf P(X{=}x, Y{=}3)+ \mathsf P(X{=}x, Y{=}4)+ \mathsf P(X{=}x, Y{=}5)\\[2ex]\mathsf P(X=2)~&=~\mathsf P(X{=}2, Y{=}3)+ \mathsf P(X{=}2, Y{=}4)+ \mathsf P(X{=}2, Y{=}5) \end{align}$$  $\sum_x\ldots$ would indicate summing over all possible $x$ values.

Answer (score 4):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_probability

If you look at the first formula in the above link, we have in your case
$P(X=x)=\sum_y P(X=x, Y=y)=\sum_y P(X=x\cap Y=y)$